# Reading from a file in C++ outputs weird characters

Tags: c++

beginner here.

I just wrote some simple code to read a file and it is (sort of) working: 
*BUT:* No matter what I do, I get "²" at the end of my output.

**Here´s my file reading code:**

```
std::string MSEshaderprogram::readFile(const std::string& filepath)
    {

        std::ifstream file{ filepath, std::ios::ate | std::ios::binary };
        
        if (!file.is_open())
        {

            MSEdebug::getInstance().debugError("Failed to open: " + filepath);

        }

        size_t fileSize = static_cast<size_t>(file.tellg());
        std::vector<char> buffer(fileSize);

        file.seekg(0);
        file.read(buffer.data(), fileSize);
        file.close();
        
        MSEdebug::getInstance().debugPassthrough(buffer.data());
        MSEdebug::getInstance().debugPassthrough("---------------------------------------------------------");

        std::string output = buffer.data();

        return output;

    }
```

**And here´s the output I get when I look at my debug Output:** *(yes I´m trying to read a vertex shader)*

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
}²²²²
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Already thank you in advance for answering.

Comment: Why are you opening the file as binary rather than as text?

Comment: You should probably null-terminate your data...Take buffer of size file_size+1 and then do buffer[file_size] = '\0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string output = buffer.data();
```

Because data is not null-terminated, your output string is formed incorrectly. Use the constructor which also takes the length, i.e.

```
std::string output(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
```

Alternatively, make sure buffer is null-terminated (by taking it one byte larger and setting the last byte to 0)

Comment: Hey, Do you mind if you could edit this so it also shows what you have to change for it to not read binary (remove std::ios::binary from the code) I think the answer would be more complete that way.

Comment: @TheBeardless: I know I wrote the comment, but I am not sure it's a problem here. Is it? If you use the recommendation in my answer alone, without removing binary, does it not work?

Comment: No, sadly it doesn´t.
it is really weird, because if i only use your approach, it doesn´t work. If i only remove the binary, it doesn´t work. But if I remove the binary AND use your answer, THEN it works.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens on this line

```
std::string output = buffer.data();
```

`buffer.data()` return a `char *`, which needs to match one of `std::string` constructors.

The best one is `std::string(const char*)` - taking a pointer to a null-terminated C string.

But `std::vector<char>` is not null-terminated, hence the `string` "runs away" past the end of the data, stopping at a random location that happens to contain 0.

You should construct the string in some other way, for example:

```
std::string output{begin(buffer), end(buffer)};
```

Or

```
std::string output{buffer.data(), buffer.size()};
```

Or perhaps read directly into a `string`:

```
std::ostringstream sstr;
sstr << file.rdbuf();
return sstr.str();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, even though reading directly to a string isn´t viable for what I´m going to need the function for in the future, you´re amazing for all the different options you show here :D